# Trying to access elements of linked-list structures in C and calling functions on struct elements

Tags: c, linked-list

I am starting out on C and i was just wondering how I would declare these linked lists structures in the main function so that I could call the functions on them, and then how I would print the values from the elements of the linked list.

Thanks for the help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {

}

struct element {
  struct element * next;
  int data;
};
struct linked_list {
  struct element * head;
};

void append_int(struct linked_list * list, int val) {
  struct element * elem = malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  elem->data = val;
  elem->next = NULL; // Really important to explicitly set this to null. Malloc does not zero memory
  if (list->head == NULL) {
    // Empty list, we need to append to head
    list->head = elem;
  } else {
    // List has some elements, find the end and append to that
    struct element * tail = list->head;
    while (tail->next != NULL) {
      tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = elem;
  }
}

void deletehead(struct linked_list * list) {
  while(list->head) {
    struct element * temp_head = list->head->next;
    free(list->head);
    list->head = temp_head;
  }
}

void inserthead(struct linked_list * list, int val) {
  struct element * new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct element));
  new_node->data = val;
  struct element * temp_head2 = list->head;
  list->head = new_node;
  new_node->next = temp_head2;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand -- you have a bunch of functions defined just fine for the structures there -- what is your question?

Comment: Is the code your? Did you find it somewhere? Do you understand the concept of pointers and how they are used? Do you know the operators used for and by pointers? Do you understand what the code you have does?

Comment: you're going to need to include the function declarations somewhere before `main` in order to suppress the "implicit declaration" warnings you will get

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, the question was how would i declare that struct in main so that I could use it with the given functions.

Comment: the `main()` implementation should come after all the other functions and structs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create the struct `linked_list`, that will hold the pointer to the first "link", the first element that is your "object" like in Object Oriented programming.

also don't forget to forward declare your functions if needed!

to create a linked list:

```
struct linked_list* list = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
```

to call functions on it:

```
inserthead(list, 5);
```

if you are coming from an oop background, all functions are static, you can think of passing the pointer to the function as calling it like "list.insert()".

Comment: I'm still getting this complier problem {                                                        error: ‘linked_list’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   struct linked_list* list = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
                                            ^
list.c:5:44: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in}

Comment: move your main under the other function or forward declare them like this
void inserthead(struct linked_list*, int);

Comment: welcome, would appreciate if you would select this answer after I edit it to mention it.